# Vitess remote connection access denied issue

Tags: mysql, authentication, access-denied, vitess

I am new on Vitess and I am trying move my mysql database on Vitess. I followed [local installation](https://vitess.io/docs/get-started/local/) instructions of vitess. I can connect mysql on local pc but when I try to connect from different pc that is on same local network, It is giving access denied error. Anyone knows what is the issue?

Connection from local pc;

[image]

.
.
.

Connection from different pc that is at same local network;
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect with same port 15306